# network problems after upgrade from wsl1 to wsl2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Today I upgraded windows 10 and switched from wsl1 to wsl2.
Most features seem to be running fine, but for some operation, I get "cannot resolve host" errors for public servers.

For instance, when I try to run visual studio code within a fresh installation of ubuntu, It can nit reach the MS download server. But other addresses ( like google) can be reached.

I tried several different fresh installs, but I get always the same problem.

Example:
    any `sudo apt install xyz`seems to work but the following install fails:

```
$ curl https://pyenv.run | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   285  100   285    0     0    219      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   219
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
```

What I noticed is that a `nslookup` on the address works quite well, but a `ping` takes aprox 7 seconds before I get the first response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can reproduce, `ping` returns instantly, and curl command also works. However, I started with a fresh WSL2 installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the WSL network interface in Windows Firewall with the following command:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I found a workaround - I set my windows dns as default dns in `/etc/resolv.conf`. This can't be the real solution, though, can it?